# How to replace bulb in this kitchen light fixture?

Tags: lighting, bulb

This LED fixture was installed only a couple of years ago in the kitchen. Light has gone dim and yellow. Cannot figure out how to open it. No holes or screws, no latches or grooves. Tried to slide it all 4 ways, doesn't budge. The transparent plastic part doesn't seem to move either. Any ideas?

Pic of fixture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMpVR.jpg

Pic 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjLb4.jpg

Comment: Have you attempted to unscrew any parts of it or simply pull straight down? Sounds like you've tried every other motion. Some of these are held in place by simple spring clips in the ceiling so prying down will move it more-or-less straight down out of the hole.

Comment: There are no visible screws. I did try pulling down but it didn't feel like there was any give.  Maybe I can try again with a little more oomph.

Comment: I meant unscrewing the entire unit. The visible bezel may be threaded into the portion that's attached to the ceiling. Twisting the whole unit (lefty-loosey) may unscrew something. If that doesn't work, try pulling down - give it enough oomph to try to get it to move, but not so much that you damage the drywall by prying. My bathroom vent fan cover pulls straight down and is held in place by spring wire. I knew that because I installed it. I tried to take the cover off and had to pull _far_ harder than I expected because of the strength of the springs.

Comment: Gotcha, I will try twisting the entire unit as well.  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Most LED cannot be repaired. You must replace it. To open it, you will probably need to take it down from the ceiling.

Comment: I should add that I am just assuming it uses LEDs, because it has a low profile and is fairly new.  If it needs to be taken down, the next question becomes how do I do that without just ripping the wall anchors out? I really don't see any access to screws or fasteners.

Comment: Try squeezing the white reflector thing. I had a similar one, and it was held in place by a lip -- no fasteners

Comment: Yes, you need to remove the lens first.  Could be any one of a number of ways it's held in place, from springs to simple gravity (i.e. push it up and slide it around).

Comment: The reflector/lens did not have any give. I will double check though, maybe see if I can pry a screwdriver in between the lens and frame. Thanks!

Comment: Since you have to replace the whole lamp anyway, you can be less than careful with it.

Comment: Fair point, I will give it a go.